# WPF: unable to map network drive for all users

Tags: c#, wpf, networking, active-directory

I'm trying to create a function for an application to automatically copy over specific files during the final stage of a job.  The only issue here is that the copy location is a protected share drive and uses a separate login instead of being validated by the active directory so I've got to do a bit of a workaround to get File.Copy() working.  My workaround has been to call the built in net.exe utility and passing a command line argument that points to the share drive to open up a connection to the drive then using File.Copy() to get the file where it needs to go then deleting the connection.  The issue at hand is that this works great on my computer but when anyone else on the team runs the same program a "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password" is thrown.  I'm at a bit of loss as to why this would happen since the username and password are static and not being changed and everyone on the team has the same network permissions I do.  Here is the WPF/C# code I'm using to do this:

```
try
{
            string mrdfDropPath = @"dropPathHere";
            string MRDFPath = @"storePath\test.xml";
            string command = @"use " + mrdfDropPath + @" /user:CORP\Username Password";
            Process.Start("net.exe", command);
            File.Copy(MRDFPath, mrdfDropPath + "test.xml");
            string command2 = @"use " + mrdfDropPath + @" /delete";
            Process.Start("net.exe", command2);
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"logPath\log.txt", true);
            writer.WriteLine(mrdfDropPath + "test.xml" + "," + File.GetLastWriteTime(MRDFPath).ToString());
            writer.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"logPath\log.txt", true);
            writer.WriteLine(e.Message);
            writer.Close();
        }
```

Like I said this works as expected during debug and when I run the application, but for anyone else it is throwing the error.

Comment: You've said username + password are static - windows wont accept 2 different logins to to the same place. Are you sure none of the others already have an area on the same server mapped

Comment: Yeah I'm sure, I'm the only one with the login info to this share drive.

Comment: and theres nothing else on the same machine? Ok.. the other obvious issue is you arent waiting for the net use to complete - so its probably trying with their permissions

Comment: No the machine for the drop location isn't mapped on anyone elses PC, that location isn't used for anything other than dropping this specific file type.  And the exception is being thrown at the Process.Start() when it is mapping the network drive and it throws a "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password" exception, the File.Copy() is never called.

Comment: interesting as it wouldnt be waiting so should have moved on irrelevant of error in your net use command

Comment: What i can't wrap my head around is why does it work when I run the code but not for anyone else?  Just compiling and running the basic .exe that is output from VS is enough to work for me but fails for everyone else.

Comment: What happens if you run the net use command directly on their machines

Comment: On one PC the command line is returning a System error 59 and on another it's returning System error 53 both An unexpected network error occured

Comment: Are they win10? and the machine they connect to not? or older OS and the machine they connect to newer?  those error codes have simple answers but if they cant do it manually your program cant do it either

Comment: Sadly now this is not an SO issue